# Javascript function is not working sometimes at certain level

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript function for hover items. İt has to work under 958px but its not working. so how can I control that. 
But when I resize page up and down, JS stops working. 
What's wrong with my function? I am unable to figure it out.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    if ($(window).width() >958){
        $('#group-subscription .owl-item').on('mouseenter', function(){
            $(this).nextAll().addClass('has-positive-translate')
            $(this).prevAll().addClass('has-negative-translate')
        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
            removeHasClasses()
        })
        function removeHasClasses() {
            $('#group-subscription .owl-item').removeClass('has-negative-translate has-positive-translate slider-hover-bigger')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You're only making the window width test once, when the page loads. If the page starts off smaller than 958 pixels wide it won't work.

Comment: Your title does not describe your problem and you have to add an event listener. Try to refrain from using titles like "Not working". It'll help you debug better. A good way I would have phrased this question if I were in your situation is "Inconsistent $(window).width() preventing function". I hope this helps you ask better questions in the future

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not related to resizing event, it only one time execute when a page is loaded and it is ready, All in all, you should use resize event instead of the ready event.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var winx = $(this);
      if (winx.height() >= 958) { 
          /*  use your code here  */
      }  
});
```